# how to remove or update custom lint

Tags: android, lint

When I wrote a custom lint and apply it to my project, I fount that it works on all projects on my computer. So I want to remove it, but it didn't work when I just delete `lintChecks project(":lint")` in Gradle. Also, it didn't work when I modify some code in the custom lint. It always works in the first draft. How can I fix it?

Ps:android studio 3.6 Beta 3, `gradle-5.6.1`, `lint-api:26.4.1`, `lint-api:26.4.1`